# DataTables add object data that is not a column to row?

Tags: javascript, datatables

I can't figure this one out, their API is very confusing.

I have a table that displays tabular data of geometric features, so I want to have the coordinates saved in the row data.

And I need a way to retrieve this coordinates, for example, when a user clicks on the row.

Example of what I'm trying to achieve :

```
const dt = $('table').DataTable({
    columns : [
        {data : "NAME"},
        {data : "COLOR"}
    ]
})

dt.row.add({
    COLOR : "Red",
    NAME : "Point1",
    //Invalid parameter error
    geometry : {
        type : "point",
        coordinates : [1,1]
    }
})
```

I think it wouldn't be ideal storing in a hidden column, because the coordinates can get quite large for polygon types.

I'm very new to DataTables and am very confused with the API, any suggestion on how to better organize/execute my concept is more than welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like what you have should work.  I put together a little example for you:
http://live.datatables.net/rikofefu/1/edit

It adds a row with the extra `geometry` object.  Select the row then click the `Show selected data` button.  The console will display the full row and just the geometry object.

I'm using the [Select extension](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/) to get the selected row.

Comment: For me the geometry prints undefined, did it work for you?

Comment: Yes, take a look at the console output.

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that :-)

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>NAME</tr>
    <tr>COLOR</tr>
    <tr></tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

JS

```
        const dt = $('table').DataTable({
        columns: [
            {data: null},
            {data: null},
            {data: null}
        ],
         // This makes the row clickable, where you can get data later
        "createdRow": function (row, data, dataIndex) {
            var tds = $(row).find("td");
            $.each(tds, function (key, value) {
                $(value).attr("onclick", "see_the_data(this)");
            }
        },
        // this hides the coordinate column from view
        "columnDefs": [
                {
                    "targets": 2,
                    "visible": false
                }
         ]
    });

    dt.row.add({
        COLOR: "Red",
        NAME: "Point1",
        //Invalid parameter error
        geometry: {
            type: "point",
            coordinates: [1, 1]
        }
    });

    function see_the_data(e) {
        console.log("the data is ", e);  // you can then go further as you need
    }
```

Comment: Could you give a brief explanation of what you did?

Comment: OK, I put a couple comments in there - not sure what more explaining I can do, though will try if you tell me what isn't clear.

Comment: Ah I understand now, but you're just storing it  as a column right? I don't know that would work very well with some coordinates that are very large

Comment: The data does not need to be in a column to be accessible.

Comment: yes, just storing it for later use (making it hidden from view so the 'large' doesn't really matter...)  I tried this on my page and it has some other errors, though it seems you found the answer you wanted, so I won't correct the code.

Comment: @KThorngren (and @Mojimi) - if the data is not in the column (or somewhere in the row), how would it be accessible?

Comment: Datatables has a cache where it stores the data for each row.  This data can be placed into a table column or not.  If you look at the example I posted you will see that it adds a row of data with all but the `geometry` object being placed into a table column.  Select this new row (Aa) then click the `Show selected data` button.  The console output shows this data is available even though its not in one of the table columns.  The HTML table is independent of the Datatables data cache.

Comment: @KThorngren - I still haven't seen your example - while I was posting my answer I saw your answer come in and I looked at the link (and see still what I see now) - only is an example of the datatables, not a table of what the OP asked for (I almost gave a -1 on the answer but the OP seemed to have seen it and liked what you did, so I ignored it - though just checking again, I have the same - - a table of <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
     </tr>

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comments regarding my example - no need for you to clarify.  However you are correct that you can store items in hidden columns.  The only reason I can see to do this though is if the data helps with table operations, like sorting.  Otherwise you are just duplicating data as it will be in both the Datatables data cache and in the table.